# Angular 5: How do I create a responsive sidebar?

Tags: html, css, angular

A lot of the suggestions online talk about using Angular Material, but I don't want to install that library just for one component.

Following the logic laid out [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp), I've created a component which works perfectly as a sidebar. The HTML of this component is very simple:

```
<div class='sidebar'>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

The bulk of the opening/closing logic is taken care of through the controller and the css.

The problem I now face is that I have a form which needs to be visible at all times on a desktop (non-sidebar view), and it gets put in the (above) closeable sidebar when the width is small.

A lot of the advice online essentially consisted of putting the content in both the sidebar as well as in the regular flow. And then just hide one of them based on the width. But this is really inconvenient for a form since I'll need to then synchronize the input variables (in the controller) for both the form instances.

I'm trying to avoid defining my form multiple times: one for sidebar view and one for non-sidebar view. Ideally, I want to just have one `<form></form>` and have it in both places. But I just can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand you want to use the same form template for your sidebar view and for the non sidebar view.

What i'd do here is use a [ReactiveForm](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and just create two FormGroups for the different views **(form_sidebar, form_nosidebar)**, create another FormGroup that is to be used in your form **(myform)** and call an event that switches the content of **myform** to the other two depending on the view.

i.e.

template:

```
<form [formGroup]="myform">
<input type="text" formControlName="input_1">
<input type="text" formControlName="input_2">
</form>

<button (click)="nosidebarView()">Without Sidebar View</button>
<button (click)="sidebarView()">Sidebar View</button>
```

controller:

```
myform: FormGroup;

constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {

}

ngOninit(){
 myform= builder.group({
   input_1: '',
   input_2: '',
 });
}
```

Comment: This would make the forms out of sync though, right? For example: when in sidebarView, I enter "abc" in input_1, then when I switch to nonsidebarView, input_1 in form_nosidebar will not have "abc". So essentially, I'll have constantly keep transferring the values from one form to the other whenever they resize their browser (and thus switching between the different views). 
Unless I misunderstood what you're saying, this is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Oh ok, i thought you'd just be utilizing the 'same' view. If you want both of them to be in sync, then just use the same FormGroup for both. I've edited the code above. Note that the controller above and the template are a component. i.e. (MyFormComponent), so in your views just call <app-myform></app-myform> where you want.